# VIM use % to select range

Tags: vim

I am used to seek for the closing bracket of a function pressing the '%' + '}' keys and it works fine but I am not able to use this way to select a range.

I would like to press the keys and then get something like
:11,31

So I could enter the command to execute on that range,I have the feeling I am missing a small bit, do I ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to type (when the cursor is on a bracket)

```
V%:YourCommand
```

`V` to enter the visual mode, line-wise, `%` to jump to the other bracket, and `:` to execute a command on the selection.

(Or `Vi%:`/`Va%:` if the cursor is not on a bracket, but within a pair of brackets-like characters)

Comment: Further to `Vi%:` you can do e.g. `Vi{`, `Vi(` to pick *which* matching brackets you select between (if you have nested structures). Also works with quotes.